# Discrete Uncorrelated Dependent Random Variables

Tags: probability

Trying to find examples of discrete and continuous random variables that are dependent and uncorrelated.

For the continuous I take standard normal $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=X^2$.  By symmetry it is clear that $E(XY) -E(X)E(Y) = E(X^3) - E(X)E(X^2) = 0 - (0)(1) = 0$, so uncorrelated.

But for events $A = \{0 < X < 1\}$ and $B = \{X^2 > 1\}$, I see that $P(A \cap B) = 0$ which does not equal $P(A)P(B)$ since both $A$ and $B$ have nonzero probability. Thus, $X$ and $Y$ are dependent and uncorrelated.

Now I am having trouble constructing a simple example with discrete random variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the simplest discrete example is $X = \begin{cases} \phantom{-}1, \\ \phantom{-}0, & \text{each with probability } 1/3, \\ -1, \end{cases}$ and $Y=X^2.$